# How to join two mysql tables twice

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables in mysql (same structure of wordpress posts db):

Table 1: "post"
id | name
1  | iphone
2  | ipad
3  | images01.jpg (thumbnail for iPhone)
4  | macbook
5  | images02.jpg (thumbnail for iPad)

Table 2: "image"
post_id  | image_id
1  | 3
2  | 5

I run the sql:

```
SELECT post.*, image.image_id FROM post 
LEFT JOIN image ON post.id = image.post_id
```

Result:

id  | name  | image_id
1  | iPhone  | 3
2  | iPad  | 5

How can I get thumbnail name (imagesxx.jpg) in the result in only one sql call?

Comment: what  is the corresponding field for thumbnail name? are you not able to get your desired output in your current query?

Comment: Looking at your sample data for `post` table, I think you need a separate field for thumbnail

Comment: thumbnail name is in Table1, but in another row

Comment: can you write out the sql? thanks

Comment: I can't change the Table1 structure. It's my wordpress post's database. I rewrite it in the simple look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aliases and join back to the post table.

```
SELECT p.*, i1.image_id image_id, p2.name image_name
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN image as i1 
   ON p.id = i1.post_id
LEFT JOIN post as p2
   ON i1.image_id = p2.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b70b4/6)

Comment: Here to help @jude Nguyen!  Would appreciate if you marked my answer as your accepted answer.

Comment: Marked. I also want click "Up arrow" for u but I can't because I have not enough rep

Answer (score 1):

That is your query:

> ```
> select p.id,p.name,p1.name from image i inner join post p on i.post_id=p.id  
> inner join post p1 on i.image_id=p1.id
> ```